# Can't remove email address from EWS contact

Tags: ews-javascript-api

I'm using the ews-javascript-api to manage my EWS contacts on an exchange server.

I'm trying to update a contact object by removing an email address.

I've followed [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/05/17/ews-managed-api-how-to-remove-email1-email2-email3-from-a-contact/) and it's got me most of the way there.  However, when I remove the ExtendedProperty's for EmailAddress1 the ews-javascript-api throws an exception due to an HTTP 500 coming back from the EWS soap request to update a contact.  Looking at the SOAP request, I can see that there is an empty FieldURI which is what the response error is complaining about.

Here is my soap request

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2"></t:RequestServerVersion>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AutoResolve">
        <m:ItemChanges>
            <t:ItemChange>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADczNzM2MTM4LTZmNWItNDBhYy05ZjcwLWUxMDc3ZDY2NjFiMABGAAAAAAC3bTmWRbrTRqYt+VZXGp68BwD5r6sZ7j5YSprMfvM2gaMkAAAAAAAQAAD5r6sZ7j5YSprMfvM2gaMkAAB4CjURAAA=" ChangeKey="EQAAABYAAAD5r6sZ7j5YSprMfvM2gaMkAAB4CkS4"></t:ItemId>
                <t:Updates>
                    <t:SetItemField>
                        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:DisplayName"></t:FieldURI>
                        <t:Contact>
                            <t:DisplayName>Craig </t:DisplayName>
                        </t:Contact>
                    </t:SetItemField>
                    <t:SetItemField>
                        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:GivenName"></t:FieldURI>
                        <t:Contact>
                            <t:GivenName>Craig</t:GivenName>
                        </t:Contact>
                    </t:SetItemField>
                    <t:DeleteItemField>
                        <t:FieldURI></t:FieldURI>
                    </t:DeleteItemField>
                    <t:DeleteItemField>
                        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:MiddleName"></t:FieldURI>
                    </t:DeleteItemField>
                    <t:DeleteItemField>
                        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:Surname"></t:FieldURI>
                    </t:DeleteItemField>
                </t:Updates>
            </t:ItemChange>
        </m:ItemChanges>
    </m:UpdateItem>
</soap:Body>
```

And here is the soap response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation
        </faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The required attribute 'FieldURI' is missing.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <e:ResponseCode
                xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation
            </e:ResponseCode>
            <e:Message
                xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.
            </e:Message>
            <t:MessageXml
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                <t:LineNumber>1</t:LineNumber>
                <t:LinePosition>1037</t:LinePosition>
                <t:Violation>The required attribute 'FieldURI' is missing.</t:Violation>
            </t:MessageXml>
        </detail>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
```

And finally here is the exception that the javascript api throws.

```
"Exception
at UpdateItemRequest../node_modules/ews-javascript-api/js/Core/Requests/ServiceRequestBase.js.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException (https://sr1.genband.com/genlync/bundle-electron.js:44707:36)
at https://sr1.genband.com/genlync/bundle-electron.js:45557:41
at <anonymous>"
```

Finally I'll mention that I can remove an email address without removing any extended properties with the following function.

```
response.EmailAddresses._setItem(ews.EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, address.value);
```

However, the problem with this is, while it looks like it works, if I try to edit that contact on my outlook web interface, I get an error about some property mismatch.  Looks like if I don't remove those extended properties when deleting an email, then they stay around and cause issues for other clients.

Comment: fixed in 0.9.3-dev.1 which is `ews-javascript-api@next` or wait for 0.9.3 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work in 0.9.3 version, available starting 0.9.3-dev.1 which is `ews-javascript-api@next` currently.